# How do I stop Javascript/HTML from editing the src (adding my server address before the link) attribute of iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to run ads in iframe of a music player. Using setInterval I am calling the playAds() method to advance in the ads array.

The code for playAds()

```
function playAds(){
  
  if(currentAd<ads.length)
  {
    if(ads[currentAd]!="")
    {
      var ad = "\""+ads[currentAd]+"\"";
      var adP = document.getElementById("adPlayer");
      adP.setAttribute("src",ad);
      console.log("Current ad - "+ad);
      currentAd++;
    }
    
  }

}
```

The issue I am facing is JS/HTML is automatically adding my server address in front with %22 at front and back making address invalid.

Console output :

[image]

Everything works fine if I paste the link directly when setting attribute of iFrame.

How do I stop this behaviour & get only link set as attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in an absolute URL instead of a relative URL.

Since your URL starts with a `"` (this becomes `%22` when [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)), and `"http://` isn't a valid scheme, it is relative.

**Don't add quote marks to the URL!** (which you do *very* explicitly on the line where you define `ad`)